# Trying to open a new Activity (Android Development) but getting the error message: /EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to teach myself Android development and I am developing a simple agenda app where you can add new assignments and keep track of due dates. However I am running into problems launching a new activity.

I know how it is supposed to be done( create an intent, use startActivity(intent) and add the activity to the Android Manifest) and have done all the necessary steps. When I run my app however, and try to click on the "Add Assignment" Button which is supposed to launch the New Assignment Activity, nothing happens and the logcat shows this error:

```
09-14 21:12:55.070    1763-1763/com.netsirk.kristen.myagenda W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

But when I press the Back button on the android emulator, the NewAssignmentActivity opens on the screen. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, here is the code for my MainActivity and NewAssignmentActivity:

Main Activity (just onCreate  method)-

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_TV);

    dueDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dueDateTextView);

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("'Today is' MMMM d',' yyyy");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    date.setText(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

    addAssignment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addAssignmentButton);

    addAssignment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View view) {
                                             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewAssignmentActivity.class);

                                             startActivity(intent);
                                         }}

    );

}
```

And this is the code (just the onCreate method) for the NewAssignmentActivity -

```
public class NewAssignmentActivity extends Activity {

private Button save, cancel;
private EditText titleEditText, detailsEditText;
private DatePicker datePicker;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_assignment);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
    titleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
    datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    detailsEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.detailsEditText);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
    final Date date = cal.getTime();

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {

                                    MainActivity.AGENDA.addAssignment(new Assignment(titleEditText.getText().toString(), date, detailsEditText.getText().toString() ));

                                }

                            }

    );

    Intent intent = new Intent(NewAssignmentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

someone please help! save button in NewAssignmentActivity doesn't work either

Comment: does ur project includes any game lib?

Comment: did u tired to reset adb?

Comment: no, how do i do that?

Comment: shortcut : in ddms there is down arrow click that there is option called reset adb.

Comment: Im sorry I dont see the down arrow.. Im using Android Studio if that makes a difference

Comment: ok got to terminal do :
-->
adb kill-server and then -->
adb start-server

Comment: I tried to reset ADB via ddms and got this message: [2014-09-14 21:46:32 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2014-09-14 21:46:32 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2014-09-14 21:53:22 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2014-09-14 21:53:22 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1

Comment: ok do one thing u can use blustack also ...if that dont wont let me know

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your emulator

Restart your emulator and then relaunch your app .

it will work